# Need a help to call a code appropriately in GAP

Tags: gap-system

I have the following input in GAP's environment:

[image]

I wanted to check whether a certain element of my Free group is **in** the group or not, so I used the code:

```
    > a in e;
```

and expected to get

```
    [ true
```

But it didn't work:

```
    [ false
```

But when I eliminated the long green [ in above pic on the right by hand, the answer got clear:

[image]

May I ask a help not to do it by hand? Thanks.

**Edit:** Here is the codes I did for a Free group for two generators. Look at the results at the end.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "eliminated the long green [" ? Also, how `a` and `w` were created? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I have a free group f:=Freegroup(3) and indeed a is as a:=f.1. I wan to examine for my self if this a is in w or not. In fact, I wanted to check this for other elements in a loop. But I couldn't do this as I wanted. I thought maybe the Long [ in the right of the first pic make my answer wrong. I removed it by hand as you see in the 2th pic and see that the answer is clear.

Comment: You are using some kind of a GAP shell which is not redistributed with GAP (apparently, GGAP), so we have to figure out whether this is a problem of theirs interface to GAP, or a problem in GAP. Unfortunately, I can't see the complete example to try in in GAP command line directly. Can you start GAP with gap.bat, and is your problem reproducible in this case?

Comment: P.S. Apparently `w` is not a free group, otherwise you can't have a list of ALL of its elements. Are you sure that `a` belongs to the right group? Is `a` in `w` or in `f`?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Dear Prof. I added something above in the body which was done in your recent GAP. I think it is the version you suggested me to use. At the end, I called "a in e" but I got false! :( Why is this happened? Shouldn't we call thin code "in" when we want to check if an element is in the structure or not? Am I missing important here? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks. GAP behaves correctly: `a` is an element of `f` and not of `w`. You may use `GeneratorsOfGroup(w)` and get **its** generators. I will post a proper answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, GAP behaves correctly here: `a` is an element of `f` and not of `w`. If you want to access generators of the newly created finitely presented group, use `GeneratorsOfGroup(w)` to get their list.

An example based on the original question, but also demonstrating how to use `ParseRelators` to simplify input:

```gap
gap> f:=FreeGroup("a","b");
<free group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> w:=f/ParseRelators(f,"a^2,b^3,(ab)^4");
<fp group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> Size(w);
24
gap> e:=Elements(w);
[ <identity ...>, a*b*a*b^-1*a*b, b, (a*b)^2, b*a*b^-1*a*b, a*b^-1*a*b*a, 
  b^-1*a*b^-1, a, b^-1, a*b^-1*a, a*b*a*b^-1, (a*b^-1)^2, a*b*a*b^-1*a, 
  b*a*b^-1, b^-1*a, b*a*b, b*a*b^-1*a, a*b^-1*a*b, b^-1*a*b*a, a*b^-1, b*a, 
  a*b, a*b*a, b^-1*a*b ]
gap> gens:=GeneratorsOfGroup(w);
[ a, b ]
gap> a:=gens[1];
a
gap> a in e;
true
```

Now quite technical detail: indeed, `a` from `f` and `a` from `w` belong to different families:

```gap
gap> FamilyObj(GeneratorsOfGroup(f)[1]) = FamilyObj(GeneratorsOfGroup(w)[1]);
false
```

This is why you were getting `false` in your examples.

Comment: P.S. Nice to see the usage of GAP 4.6 here. Note that while running GAP in `mintty` shell it is very easy to copy and paste the text from the terminal instead of making a snapshot of the screen (then I wouldn't have to retype the input manually). Also, you can customise font size and colours, and these settings will be preserved for future GAP installations.

Comment: P.P.S.: Any particular reasons why this has not been asked under ["gap" tag at MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap)? I think dispersing GAP related questions across several Q&A sites is not helpful, and MSE already has more questions with more views, so GAP users among MSE audience will easier discover questions asked there, not here.

Comment: Thanks so much Prof. Konovalov. Indeed, your first comments above gave me the right key and showed me to work with the version you suggested me before. I see now that the version of Prof. Alexander Hulpke has some very small defects. Let me see your attempt above step be step. Thanks again and have a good time in Groups St Andrews 2013. I wish I had been there to attend your sessions.

Comment: Thanks - you're welcome. As for the suggested "defect", I think that's not true - underneath the Windows Installer by Alexander Hulpke is same GAP 4.4.12 with slightly smaller selection of packages and with the GGAP GUI to GAP (not yet updated for GAP 4.5+). What you observe is likely a side-effect of a common "feature" of all GUIs for CASs: if you execute a sequence of commands A;B; where the result of B depends on the result of A, and then return to A, change it and execute A again, C and its output remain unchanged, so the view of your CAS session is no longer consistent.